# How to import say 1million bitcoin privkeys in bitcoind / bitcoin-qt?

Tags: private-key

I was wondering if there are ways to automate / mass private key import into the bitcoin client. Anyone knows of a command or has a script or an idea to share?

thanks.

Comment: Export the keys from your current client (which should be just a few) and then replace your `wallet.dat` with the same file from the wallet that hold the 1 million private keys, then import your original keys and you're all set.

Comment: Use the importwallet command. Try dumpwallet to see thr file format.

Answer (score 3):

Well...
You could automate it using the JSON RPC and slowly work through the keys, however this will be kinda slow. If you actually need to work with 1 million keys, you may need to consider an alternative option.

What is it you need to do with the keys?